# Use NSFetchRequest to get all results of relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchrequest

I have two entities: Author and Book. I want to get the list of all books by a particular author.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Books"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY author == %@", author]];
books = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

However, this returns only one book of the author.

How can I get ALL books of a particular author?

I read a bunch of other topics but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the data model: relationship author -> book should be "To many" instead of "To one".

After updating the relationship I had to reinstall the app in the simulator, but everything worked properly after that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try like this ?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Books"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author = %@", author ];
NSArray *matches = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but it still returns only one result. If I remove the predicate row, it shows all books of all authors.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but are you sure there's more than one author that matches your predicate ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have another ViewController that I use for creating new books and whenever I add a book, only that book is returned using the predicate above.

Comment: Hm, you might pointed me in the right direction - double checking now the code that saves new books. Will post back shortly :)

Comment: The issue was in the data model - relationship was set to one-to-one, instead of one-to-many. Thank you very much, your answer pushed me in the right direction!